# Django (REST) backend server hosting using Google Cloud

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, web-hosting

This is my first time trying to host a backend server to any cloud platform and I am trying to host it using Google Cloud. This is a pet project of mine and the frontend of my webapp is alreday hosted by myself using firebase.
My issue is I tried depolying the cloud app for my backend, but I am getting a `500 server error` even though the files were uploaded without any issues. Another thing is I am quiet not sure about my file structure.
[Backend File Strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLAtJ.png)
[API folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGGKQ.png)
[enchant_ease_backend File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ4hH.png)
[My backend folder](https://github.com/ThisalHerath/express-hello-world)

I tried removing my `requirements.txt` file since in the Google cloud app engine dashboard I got few errors with my dependencies but id did not worked out and I spent almsot few hours watching tutorials but nothing worked out.

Can someone guide me through the hosting  process or tell me what i have done wrong or something that need to be changed?